# Symonfy form: display input according to value of other field (Twig)

Tags: symfony, twig, symfony-2.1, symfony-forms

### Problem

I have a form in my Symfony 2(.1.8) application for creating an entry in a table called `media`. I build the form with the buildForm function in my media form class.
Amongst other fields the `media` table has these 3 fields: `url`, `mediatype` and `file`.

The `mediatype` is a relationship with a `mediatype` table and I render it as a drop down with the two values: `VIDEO` and `IMAGE`.

What I want to do now:
When the user selects `VIDEO` in the dropdown the `url` form_row should be visible. When he selects `IMAGE` in the dropdown, the `file` form_row should be visible. When the user hasn't selected anything yet, neither `url` or `file` should be visible. 
I tried this with this piece of code (but offcourse it's not working because the form.vars isn't dynamic I guess?):

```
 {% if form.vars.value.mediatype == "video" %}
     {{ form_row(form.url, { 'attr': {'class': 'form_url'} }) }}
 {% elseif form.vars.value.mediatype == "image" %}
     {{ form_row(form.file, { 'attr': {'class': 'form_file'} }) }}
 {% endif %}
```

### Question

Is there a good way to do this using Twig and/or the Symfony framework? I was thinking of doing it with Javascript, but I first want to know for sure if it isn't possible with Twig/Symfony itself?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I was thinking of doing it with Javascript, but I first want to know for sure if it isn't possible with Twig/Symfony itself?

First idea is always the best one ;) Twig is a template language and is parsed server side. The idea of yours to just hide the other field with `javascript` is a good way to handle these things.

**But** there is an important thing to note! I guess only one of the fields `url` and `file` has to be filled out. With a plain Javascript solution always both of the fields will be send to your app. Therefore Symfony2 provides form events. There is a [whole chapter in the cookbook](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) about them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Hadn't come across the form events page yet, gonna look into them now :)